# UK visa application: How to explain that I have several employers?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm a doctor applying to a UK visa for an examination. I am employed by the university hospital in my city but I also work in several private hospitals  where I earn several times the salary I receive from the university. How can I explain that in my visa application? There's only one "employer" slot and I think it should be for the university job.
How then, can I explain my other earnings? Should I state that I am also "Self-employed" or should this go under the "other incomes" sections?
Also, Do you think there'd be problems with my application since I receive my private practice income in cash directly from the hospitals and deposit it in the bank myself every month? specially, since that it's about 6 times the official university salary. Also, I may not be able to provide evidence of payments from some of these hospitals!

Comment: How do you pay taxes if you cant prove receipt of payment for work done?  Thats not a frivolous question either, because thats going to be exactly what the immigration official will be thinking when you present them with the above - up to that point in your post, my response was going to be "write a cover letter explaining, calling out the deposits and linking them to pay slips from alternative employers" but then you clarified that its basically cash in hand, which opens up a can of worms.

Comment: Reporting income can be a significant challenge. You might review [this Travel:SE question and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: I can show pay slips covering most of my extra income, however some of it (about 20%) is totally cash in hand with no written proofs. What do you think might improve my chances of successful application?

Comment: Start getting evidence for *all* income and put off your visa application until you have several months’ worth. There are many examples on TSE of refusals due to unexplained/undocumented deposits, 20% is a significant proportion

Comment: Thank you for the replies. That 20% comes directly from assisting a senior doctor I work with where he gives me the money directly out of the money he earns himself from surgeries. If I get him to sign a statement  that he gives me an X amount of money each month for assisting him, Would that carry any weight to help with my application??

Comment: I would imagine that you have to pay tax on the 20% anyway, no matter where it comes from @EssamZaher so you must be tracking it in some way to know how much tax to pay. Show that.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for details.
But in short, include information for all income you have. Copies of contacts, signed letters that this person employed you and paid you X money.

See this comment by @traveller

> Start getting evidence for all income and put off your visa application until you have several months’ worth. There are many examples on TSE of refusals due to unexplained/undocumented deposits, 20% is a significant proportion.

Write a cover letter to include this information if there is not enough space on the form, but if at all possible make a note on the form where the information about that money is.
A tax form on which you declare that cash in hand money will help as well, if you do not yet pay tax over it, consider doing so, to avoid problems in the future.